# How do I access OneDrive data for a tenant who isn't on the multi-tenant space for Office365?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

We have a tenant that doesn't exist on the multi-tenant space (-my.sharepoint.com)

It's a special deployment from MSFT and the My Site collection is abc.pqr.com. A sample OneDrive site is as follows (it does point to a OneDrive, I haven't pasted the correct url here)

```
https://abc.pqr.com/personal/user_name_domain_com
```

I wish to access the Meta for Web as follows

```
https://abc.pqr.com/personal/user_name_domain_com/_api/web
```

I am using Client Credentials Flow to get access token but I can't seem to authenticate the following resource

```
https://abc.pqr.com/
```

It says "invalid_resource".

```
{"error":"invalid_resource","error_description":"AADSTS50001: The application named https://abc.pqr.com was not found in the tenant named blablablalbla.  This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant.  You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.\r\nTrace ID: blablablalbl\r\nCorrelation ID: xyz\r\nTimestamp: blablaZ","error_codes":[50001],"timestamp":"blablaZ","trace_id":"blablabla","correlation_id":"blabla"}
```

My question is, how do I access it? How do I authorize this domain? Which authentication mechanism would work?